# Not able to put a condition in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am new to shell scripting
I have been trying to create a shell script which runs on every month end. But the script doesn't run on Sundays and Mondays.
Only Tues-Sat. So if the month end falls on sun or mon, it will run 28th or 29th.
Eg- if a month is of 30 days then ideally script should run on 30.
But if 30th falls on Sunday then the script should run on 29th.

Can anybody please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to post their efforts in form of code in their questions. So please do add the same along with your clear sample output/expectation and let us know then.

Comment: Hello Anshika. I suggest you read this post https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to ask good questions in stackoverflow. The chances of you getting an answer will be much higher. For example, you could add to your question how are you trying to schedule the script, and if you are using corn, what is the actual line in your crontab.

Comment: You should also indicate if you are doing this strictly for learning, or if you are trying to fullfill it for your job. If your job is in a regulated industry, you'll also need to allow for skipping holidays and bunch of other possibilities, which all really point to using a database with a calendar of holidays (which has to be maintained annually). ***Please don't reply in comments, but update your question and leave a comment that you have updated your question.*** Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Although I strongly agree with the comments, I must say I'm a sucker for a good challenge.
I would use a wrapper script, run it each day at 23:00 or whatever time the job should be run. That wrapper script just determine on which day that job should run for the current month and then if the current day is the right one, actually run the job.

Something like that :

```
#!/bin/bash
#######################################################
#
# Script to determine if end of month job should run today
#
# datetorun.sh
#
# Usage : datetorun.sh
#
# version=1.0.0
# Andre Gelinas 2020
#######################################################

CurrentDate=( $(date +"%Y %m %d") )

####################
function MaxDayOfMonth
####################
# How many days per month. Parameter YYYY
{
typeset locYEAR
typeset locMONTH
typeset locMAX_DAY
typeset i

locYEAR=$1

for ((i=1;i<=12;i++)); do
        locMONTH=$i
        if [[ $locMONTH == @(1|3|5|7|8|10|12) ]]; then
                locMAX_DAY=31
        elif [[ $locMONTH == @(4|6|9|11) ]]; then
                locMAX_DAY=30
        elif [[ $locMONTH == "2" && ( $((locYEAR%4)) == 0 && ( $((locYEAR%100)) != 0  || $((locYEAR%400)) == 0 ) ) ]]; then
                locMAX_DAY=29
        else
                locMAX_DAY=28
        fi
        DAY_OF_THE_MONTH[$i]=$locMAX_DAY
done
}

######################
function DayOfWeek
######################
# This function returns the day of week where
# 0 = sunday, 1 = monday, ... 6 = saturday
# This algorithm is from Mike Keith's World of Words & Numbers:
# http://www.cadaeic.net/calendar.htm
# arguments: $1 = month, $2 = day, $3 = year in format YYYY
# [.] means to truncate downward to the nearest integer
# dayofweek=([23m/9] + d + 4 + y + [z/4] - [z/100] + [z/400] - 2 (if m >= 3)) mod 7
{
typeset -i locDOW
typeset -i z
typeset -i multpr

if [[ $1 -lt 3 ]]; then
# year determination
   z=$(($3-1))
else
   z=$3
fi
if [[ $1 -ge 3 ]]; then
# set the multiplier
   multpr=2
else
   multpr=0
fi

locDOW=$(( ((23 * $1/9) + $2 + 4 + $3 + ($z/4) - ($z/100) + ($z/400) - $multpr) % 7))

DOW=$locDOW
}

MaxDayOfMonth ${CurrentDate[0]}

DayOfWeek ${CurrentDate[1]} ${DAY_OF_THE_MONTH[${CurrentDate[1]}]} ${CurrentDate[0]}
# OR as per comments you can use this instead :
# DOW=$(date -d ${CurrentDate[0]}${CurrentDate[1]}${DAY_OF_THE_MONTH[${CurrentDate[1]}]} +"%w")

case $DOW in
    0)  DateToRun=$(( ${DAY_OF_THE_MONTH[${CurrentDate[1]}]}-1 ))
        ;;
    1)  DateToRun=$(( ${DAY_OF_THE_MONTH[${CurrentDate[1]}]}-2 ))
        ;;
    *)  DateToRun=${DAY_OF_THE_MONTH[${CurrentDate[1]}]}
        ;;
esac

if [[ $DateToRun -eq ${CurrentDate[2]} ]]; then
    echo "Running the script"
else
    echo "Not Running the script"
fi
```

EDITED as per comments

Comment: Why does the method `DayOfWeek` exist? It seems to do the same like `date +%w`.

Comment: LOL...you're right ! Forgot about it. Love that function and using it since I've found it. Just a reflex of mine.